# Is there an easy way to get access to a component from anywhere?

Tags: polymer

Right now i'm doing something like this:

```
    function getChartPages() { 
          return document.querySelector("dashboard").shadowRoot.querySelector("#panelA").shadowRoot.querySelector("#panelA3").shadowRoot.querySelector("#panelA3south"); 
    }
```

I wonder if there's an easy way to achieve the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelector('dashboard /deep/ #panelA3south')` would get you want you want. You can also use `::shadow` in qS().

It's worth noting that 'dashboard' is not a valid custom element name. There needs to be a "-" in the name.